# use font in Fragment

Tags: android

I tend to use the font fragment and fragment have control over 
Why the following code produces an error?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rooo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.din2, container, false);
        TextView tv1=(TextView) rooo.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Typeface yaghut=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font/BKOODB.ttf");
        tv1.setTypeface(yaghut);
        return rooo;
    }

    }
```

this error
[image]

Comment: >>"View rooo =". >>"return roo" where's the last 'o'?

Comment: do you have a directory inside assets called font?

Answer (score 3):

`onCreateView`  is supposed only to return the view that represent the fragment. Other operations on the View should be performed in another callback, `onViewCreated`

```
    @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.din2, container, false);
 }

 @Override 
 public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tv1=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Typeface yaghut=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font/BKOODB.ttf");
        tv1.setTypeface(yaghut);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need change :

```
TextView tv1=(TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

to

```
 TextView tv1=(TextView) rooo.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

because your `TextView` with `tv1` id's must be on `din2` layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a view named `rooo` but you are returning a view named `roo`...now replace all `roo` with `rooo` as below...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rooo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.din2, container, false);
    TextView tv1=(TextView) rooo.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    Typeface yaghut=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font/BKOODB.ttf");
    tv1.setTypeface(yaghut);
    return rooo;
}

}
```